# Ag-grid : hide column sidebar when clicked outside of side bar panel in angular

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-ng2

Does anyone know how to hide ag-grid side bar when clicked outside of it? I am able to do it on button click but not able to find how to do collapse it when clicked outside of sidebar

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it as false

```
this.gridApi.setSideBarVisible(false)  // hide
this.gridApi.setSideBarVisible(true)    // show
```

You can handle events using:-

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-selection

Check available grid events like **onCellClicked, onCellFocused** etc:-

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/side-bar/#side-bar-api

Also:-

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
}

  onKeyDown = (e) => {      
      // check sidebar is visible
   
     if(this.gridApi.isSideBarVisible()){
    // code here
     }
  }
```

Comment: didn't work. Actually after setting this column sidebar doesn't open

Comment: On outside click you just need to call grid events and   set it as false

this.gridApi.setSideBarVisible(false).  Updated answer.

Comment: It worked on cell events.Thanks,
However is there any way that i can track a click outside of tool panel? because it dont work if i click outside the grid

Comment: just check sidebar visible and close using addEventListener. Accept it as answer if it helped.